# Differentiate between strings and embedded messages

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

As an exercise i am trying to write a GPB decoder. According to [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) document strings and embedded messages (among others) has the same type, so how do you differentiate between a string and an embedded message? From my understanding, a string has to be decoded using a different method than a  embedded message.

Answer (score 0):

This information is conveyed in the `.proto` file. To properly decode a protobuf message, the decoder has to know the type of the message beforehand and also have available the according `.proto` file.

The `.proto` file can be accessed most easily by first compiling the file using `protoc` and then reading the output file, which is itself a protobuf message defined in the file [descriptor.proto](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto). In this file, identifiers `TYPE_MESSAGE` and `TYPE_STRING` tell the difference between the types that use the same `wire_type` in the encoding.